# How to install for Solr 1.4 ( or 1.4.1 ) Extended Dismax (edismax) plugin and how to configure it?

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax

Im using Solr1.4 , with dismax SearchHandler , I'm new to solr ;), it seems not supporting lucene syntax , it does not even match lowercase uppercase terms ( if you know how to do this it will be helpfull ).

I want to try the edismax, (Extended Dismax) with solr 1.4 or 1.4.1 , I found it in solr 4.0 dev version, there is not  a lot of documentation  about it .

I'm using solr with windows server.

Is it possible to patch my current version to use edismax?
what about edismax configuration, does it use the same params as the standard dismax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since edismax is an experimental, not-yet-finished feature, you'll have to get the [Lucene/Solr source code](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/version_control.html), and build it.

Again because this is not released, your only documentation are the [JIRA comments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1553) and [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin.java?view=markup).